# Google docs : make one or more landscape page on a portrait document

Tags: google-docs

I am working on a document on google doc. I have a large table to add to my document and I am wondering, is there any way to make one or more landscape pages on a portrait document. I tried to insert a page break and to change after the orientation of my page but it is not working. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: I'm quite sure it is impossible, but lets see what others think.

Comment: There is a detailed answer on the web apps stack exchange: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/20258/google-docs-make-a-single-page-landscape

Comment: Now it's possible!!! in 2021:D https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10296604?hl=en

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nope, not at this stage. I wish there was. This would increase compatibility with a lot of documents I get send from Word.

Would love to take you to the feature request page but this is the closest I can find. Put your vote in! 
http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!searchin/docs/landscape/docs/ElJ8Jp1O724/6Mjw8kRq_doJ

Source: 
https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/docs/formatting/oSSv-MZqzys

Comment: Now it's possible!!! in 2021:D https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10296604?hl=en